# Add AngularJS files while loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

So I'm trying to load all the `AngularJS` scripts which I need in my app when the `index.html` file loads.

For this I've made this piece of code

```
 <head>
        ...
           AngularJS libaries loads
        ...

        <script>
            var main = {
                    root: [
                        'core.js'
                    ]
                };

            var iterateScripts = function(folder, path){
                for(var key in folder){
                    if(key.toLowerCase() === 'root'){
                        for(var i = 0; i < folder[key].length; i++){
                            var script = document.createElement('script');
                            script.type = 'text/javascript';
                            script.src = path + '/' + folder[key][i];
                            // console.info('script : '+ script.src)
                            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var newPath = path + '/' + key;
                        // console.info('path : ', newPath, folder[key])
                        iterateScripts(folder[key], newPath);
                    }
                }
            };

            iterateScripts(main, 'app/main');
            console.info(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0])
        </script>
   </head>
```

This loads the files okay, but I get this error

[AngularJS error explanation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=SimPlannerApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.7%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DSimPlannerApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:24:186%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:23:252)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:23:495%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:37:427%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20h%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:41:35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F_core%2FCore%2520Development%2Flib%2FAngularJS%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:19:463)

After testing back and forth I've concluded that the problem is because the page loads while AngularJS is compiling, which creates the error.

If this is true, how can I load my angular app in a similar fashion before the `body` tag loads?

Comment: This is not an answer, but there are better options. Consider using something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or JSPM if you're willing to use ES6 imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to bootstrap angular yourself instead of using ng-app. Here is the documentation on it: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap.

Once all your scripts are finished loading then you'll run a piece of code that looks similar to this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Which tells angular it is ready to start.

Comment: That worked, had to set a timer thou to ensure that the files had loaded ^^

Comment: Don't set a timer, use the onload property.

Comment: How would I check if all the files has loaded before running the bootstrap?

Comment: What I said above, use the onload property for each script. Simplest solution would be to use a counter. If the counter equals total javascript files you needed to load then you can bootstrap.